# Jquery accordion height overflowing

Tags: jquery, jsp, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using jquery 1.9.1. In my accordion, the height is assigned according to the heightStyle value ( i.e. 'content' of 'fill').

In one of the panes, I am using for loop to render a list. This panes is always overflowing, no matter what property i set.

Here is my JSP:

```
<style>
      #accordion-resizer {
          padding: 10px;
          width: 350px;
          height: 220px;
      }
</style>
<script>
      $(function() {
          $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
              heightStyle: "fill",
              autoHeight: false
          });
      });
      $(function() {
          $( "#accordion-resizer" ).resizable({
              minHeight: 140,
              minWidth: 200,
              resize: function() {
                   $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
              }
          });
      });
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="accordion-resizer" class="ui-widget-content">
        <div id="accordion" style="font-size: medium;">
            <h3>Projects</h3>
            <div>
                <p>
                <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="projects" >
                    <c:forEach items="${projects}" var="project" varStatus="status">
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center">${status.count}</td>
                            <td><input name="projects[${status.index}].projectId"
                                value="${project.projectId}" /><br /></td>
                        </tr>
                    </c:forEach>

                    <button type="submit"></button>
                </form:form>
                </p>
            </div>
            <h3>Excepteur sint occaecat</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
                <p>tempora incidunt ut labore</p>
            </div>
            <h3>Other Info</h3>
            <div>
                <p>Neque porro quisquam </p>
                <p>Sed eleifend nonummy </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The first pane, after loading, expands the form and thus, overflows. The other panes, which are otherwise of normal height, also adopt to this new height.
I have tried:

> heightStyle: "fill" and 
>   heightStyle: "content"

both are not able to stop the first pane from blowing out.

Comment: Does the same thing happen if you use HTML only (with no JSP)?

Comment: No, it does not. This happens only within a JSP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a lot, finally I found the solution. It was happening because accordion panes had variable length. 
This setting prevents panes from overflowing, adds a nice scroll bar

```
  #accordion .ui-accordion-content {
    max-height: 500px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Thank you